# How to test for changes in 6 yes / no questions assessed before and after treatment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, categorical-data

Young children were given a questionnaire before and after a presentation.  There were 6 questions to answer yes or no.  I would like to find out if there is a significant difference between the questionnaires taken before and after the presentation.

I could score each test and do repeated measures testing, but the questions do not necessarily have right or wrong answers, so I would like to treat it as binary data.

I would also like to test for each question.  For example, on the first question, there were 12 yes answers before the presentation, and 43 yes answers after.

Comment: Do you know which before scores go with which after scores?

Answer (score 1):

The [McNemar test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) is designed for assessing pre-post matched sample data on a binary variable. Thus, you could use that for each of your six questions.

That said, most researchers in your context don't ask six independent questions. Rather, the six questions often have some structure. In some cases the questions are true-false and are scored based on the number of items correct (but not in your case, as you have stated). In other cases, the items form a scale or a few subscales. In general, such scales or subscales can provide a more parsimonious overall picture of any effect of an intervention on test scores. Thus, you may want to think about whether such overall scales exist in your data. If so, you could then turn to something like Wilcoxon sign test (ordinal) or possibly a paired samples t-test (numeric).